# TextButton hover option, or something similar?

Tags: button, libgdx, hover, imagebutton

As I know, there are three types of buttons in LibGDX:

`TextButton`, `ImageButton` and `ImageTextButton`

I need to create a button with my own background and own text and of course, but I also need a hover option.

The hover is available in ImageButton, but ImageButton doesn't have a label so I can't assign any text to it.

There is a third option, ImageTextButton, but it's not a normal button, it's a button and a label which is set next to it (which is unacceptable, cause I need the text on the button).

Is there any option to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by hover option?

Comment: Buttons are subclasses of Table. ImageTextButton comes "preloaded" with an image and a label, but if you don't like that, you can clear the children after you create it. eg, button = new ImageTextButton(); button.clearChildren(); button.add(aLabel); You now have a plain text button, but with the ImageTextButtonStyle that mimics the hover that the ImageButton has. Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: `ButtonStyle` has `over` drawable, which is set as the button background on mouse hover. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, yes yes! The over parameter, I just didn't notice the inheritance Button > TextButton and didn't know that they inherit it's parameters. Post this as an answer, if you can! :)